# Pandas dataframe doesn't find colunm name KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=';', header=0, encoding='latin_1')
```

The content of my CSV separted by semicolon

```
num_report; date_hour_ocorrence; Nº_involved; conductor; cod_severity; 
2019-007782512-001;18/02/2019 19:24;3;Y;1
2019-007782515-001;20/02/2019 08:44;4;N;3
```

But when I try do this:

```
df.loc[df['conductor'] == 'S']
```

I got the error

```
KeyError: 'conductor'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: It looks like your column is `' conductor'` note the leading whitespace.

Comment: @HenryEcker thats it!!! do you know how can I filter my header eliminating white spaces? is that an encoding type?

Comment: Take a look at your input file. The split delimiter is ';' and there is whitespace on the header row that is not present in other rows. You could fix that row or

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` should work to programmatically strip after reading in the DataFrame or add `, skipinitialspace=True` to `read_csv`  to skip leading whitespace after the separator. Take a look at the duplicate below: